# Android, user send push notification when button clicked

Tags: android, push-notification

Is there way a user can send a push notification when button clicked like push notification but from inside the application? . I tried to use local notifications but the notification is sent only to the user device and not to all the devices the app is installed on.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why you don't send a request to your server to trigger the push notification to all the devices?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually i need a notification to be send to all the user's devices when a user click a button . Can you explain more what do you mean?

Comment: I mean a button isinside my app

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your server, write addition Api that trigger push notification.